# Implement Framework7 calendar on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I'm trying to add framework7 calendar on HTML-page, but it doesn't show up. What can be the problem?

My html-code:

```
  <div class="content-block-title">Default setup</div>
    <div class="list-block">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Your birth date" readonly id="calendar-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My js-code

```
var myApp = new Framework7();
var calendarDefault = myApp.calendar({
input: '#calendar-default',
});
```

Comment: first of all, is the comma after `input: '#calendar-default',` there by accident?

Comment: Get rid of that comma after `input:'#calendar-default'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the DOM is not ready yet, in particular the '#calendar-default' input element. You can check if that's the problem using this line just before you initialize the calendar:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('calendar-default'));
```

If it prints 'null' than that's your problem.

The solution depends on your context. You can solve it by using [Dom7](https://framework7.io/docs/dom.html) (part of Framework7) and listening to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
$$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarDefault = myApp.calendar({
        input: '#calendar-default',
    });
});
```

If you're using it with [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) or some sort of client side MV-* framework the initialization logic may need to go in some life-cycle-method (I'm using [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) and had this problem when tried to create a datepicker [custom component](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3)).